# Dynamic composite part eclipse e4

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm facing a pretty annoying issue and I'm wondering if someone knows how to deal with it.
I have an Eclipse RCP e4 application, which creates dynamic parts based on the content of a file.

For each file, the created part has to show side by side two tables (implemented as NatTables), which must be horizontally resizable (e.g., master-detail)

When I started, I thought that a good way was to use dynamic composite part, which cannot be added neither as part descriptors nor as snippets in the application model.
From my understanding, the purpose of a composite part is also to deal with this kind of scenarios, but I couldn't find a way to use them dynamically.

To have something working, I switched to this code, which redraws the two tables based on a constant by adding a listener to the SWT.Resize event. Though, this code does not exactly what I want to do.

```java
public void postConstruct(Composite parent,EMenuService menuService){       
    ...
    Shell shell = parent.getShell();
    Point size = shell.getSize();
    leftGridData.widthHint = (int)(size.x * leftProportion);
    rightGridData.widthHint = size.x - leftGridData.widthHint;

    // adding this configuration adds the styles and the painters to use
    _tableViewLeft.setLayoutData(leftGridData);
    _tableView.setLayoutData(rightGridData);

    _tableView.configure();
    // Tooltip for row/column headings

    shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            Point size = shell.getSize();

            leftGridData.widthHint = (int) (size.x * leftProportion);
            rightGridData.widthHint = size.x - leftGridData.widthHint;
            shell.redraw();
        }
    });
}
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to resize horizontally the two tables inside a dynamic part. The two tables shall use all the space to fit the available space. Any hint or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For GridLayout all you need to do is specify 'SWT.FILL' and 'grab extra space' for the layout data of the two controls. No need to listen for resize.

```java
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, true);
composite.setLayout(layout);

...

GridData leftGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
leftControl.setLayoutData(leftGridData);

...

GridData rightGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
rightControl.setLayoutData(rightGridData);
```

If you want to be able to manually adjust the spacing look at the `Sash` and `SashForm` controls.

Comment: SashForm is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

While the NatTable respects the SWT layout (as @greg-449 suggests and I also recommend as the correct solution), the columns inside a NatTable instance by default don't resize to take all the available space. The column width has a fixed size unless you configure it differently. So once you fixed the SWT layout issue, you also need to configure the NatTable for percentage sizing, which means that the column width is calculated based on the available container width. This can be done via `DataLayer#setColumnPercentageSizing(boolean)`